# Exclude specific standard library functions from VS2010 C++ Compiler

Tags: c++

is there a way to deactivate certain functions of the standard Library in C++ for the VS2010 compiler?
For example, if i want that a team cant use std::max or std::min and in case they still do the compiler should give an error. Is that possible? How could i do that?

Thanks and best regards,
Ben

Comment: You can enforce including a header file which `#defines` these functions as empty macros, rendering them unusable.

Comment: What have you found out so far?

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz: Which also makes them unusable to the standard library itself. No, bad idea.

Comment: @MSalters if you include that file as the last one, why should it make them unusable to the standard library?

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz: Because there's no concept as "the last one" when you consider code in your own headers. After preprocessing, that in general ends up interleaved with std code. Hence, when the macro follows the last std code, it does not cover all your own code.

Comment: @MSalters well, I didn't mean to include it in headers

Answer (score 0):

Don't. There is no good reason, and your example (`std::max`) certainly isn't.

Answer (score -1):

You can redefine the functions you don't want to be used, and so long as they get pulled in before the std library the compiler will use yours.  You could then use the #error tag to flag it up during the compilation.

```
namespace std {
    template <class T> const T& min ( const T& a, const T& b )
    {
        #error("Don't use this")
    }
    template <class T, class Compare>
    const T& min ( const T& a, const T& b, Compare comp )
    {
        #error("Don't use this")
    }
}

#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    return std::min(5, 4);
}
```

Comment: That's a rather bad solution, and `#error` is part of the preprocessing stage.

Comment: So what's wrong with this?  @ben1980 could have a better function, perhaps using additional hardware he wants to ensure is being used.

Comment: `#error` will trigger in the preprocessing stage, thus this code will never compile.

Comment: That's how I understood the question.  If the std library functions are used by mistake, he wants the compiler to generate an error.

Comment: @dwxw: And if they're NOT used, they should NOT generate an error.

Comment: @MSalters: Ah, see what you mean! Opps.

Comment: hom ok i see its not that easy as we hoped. The reason is that we get problems with std:max/min while cross compiling for linux for some reasons. If it would be only Windows there would be no problem.

Comment: @Ben1980: Then ask the real question. There should be no reason for `std::min/max` to fail on Linux.

Comment: I am gonna asko tomorrow the one who is doing it. But as far as i know i gives problems in combination with #include <algorithm> while compiling in qt creator with gcc